# Изменение данных в ячейке DataGrid

Tags: c#, datagrid, wpf, mvvm

Всем привет!

Есть `DataGrid`, к нему привязана некоторая коллекция, я хочу изменять данные в одном столбце (типа `double`), валидировать их и в зависимости от значения пересчитывать значение в другом столбце (`double`).

Проблема в том, что я не могу получить новое значение, которое ввёл в ячейку. Я использую команду `ChangeCellCommand`, и при её вызове у меня в ячейке хранится старое значение. Если в столбце в привязке указать `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`, то я получаю новое значение. Но тут возникает другая проблема - я не могу в ячейку вводить ни точку, ни запятую, только целые числа. Подскажите, как лучше сделать? Или, может, есть другая команда при изменении значения ячейки?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Какой тип коллекции вы биндите, лучше всего использовать `ObservableCollection<T>`, тогда при изменении данных в ячейке, изменится и объект коллекции. А для класса этих объектов можно имплементировать `INotifyPropertyChanged` и тогда после изменения свойства можно автоматически менять и другие свойства объекта.